# change appcompat dialog title background to full width?

Tags: android, android-layout, android-appcompat

I want to change title color background(green) to full width.

```css
    <style name="AppCompatAlertDialogStyle" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.Dialog.Alert">
        <item name="colorAccent">#000000</item>
        <item name="android:textColorPrimary">#5c5c5c</item>
        <item name="android:background">#fbdd9d</item>
        <item name="android:windowTitleStyle">@style/TitleDialogTextStyle</item>
    </style>

    <style name="TitleDialogTextStyle" parent="Base.DialogWindowTitle.AppCompat">
        <item name="android:textColor">#ffffff</item>
        <item name="android:background">@color/green</item>
    </style>
```

Please find attached snap. I want  green color to full width.
[image]

Comment: is there anyone who can give me some idea?

Answer (score 0):

I made a lot of tries, I never succeded to change the color defining a custom 
`android:windowTitleStyle` or a `android:windowTitleBackgroundStyle`.
It only works using the following trick, add to your custom dialog style :

```
<item name="android:topDark">@color/your_color</item>
```

And the title background will be colored as you want.